# Interpolation in @import path with Stylus

Tags: css, stylus

Although I've read the variables and interpolation parts of the Stylus docs I can't seem to get this to work.

```
dirs = {
    vendor: '../../../public/vendor/'
}
@import '{dirs.vendor + "normalize-css/normalize.css"}'
```

Gives:

```
failed to locate @import file {dirs.vendor + "normalize-css/normalize.css"}
```

Is this possible in Stylus? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it is possible. But Stylus currently doesn't have a string interpolation so you should use concatenation:

```
dirs = {
    vendor: '../../../public/vendor/'
}
@import dirs.vendor + "normalize-css/normalize.css"
```